# How to mute notifications on macOS Sierra?

Tags: keyboard, notifications, macos, shortcut

Before macOS Sierra I could do "alt + mouse click" on notifications icon (placed on the top right corner of screen, on the menu bar).

It doesn't seem to work on Sierra. How to mute notifications on Sierra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

⌥-clicking on <sub>[image]</sub> works fine for me in macOS Sierra, but you can also enable Do Not Disturb by opening Notification Center, scrolling up and sliding the switch to On.

[image]